# How to convert python code to Spark compatible Code (pyspark)?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark code which can extract the required names from the piece of text.This codes gives me the results,but takes hell lot of time to process on my large data as some part of it is more pythonic.Request your help to convert it into more pyspark way to improve the efficiency (new to spark environment)

```
articles=sc.textFile("file:///home//XXX//articles.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(","))
articles_ls=list(articles.map(lambda x: [x[0].lower(),x[1].lower(),x[2].lower(),x[3].lower().strip()]).collect())

                 #Function which needs to be optimized to run faster
def mapper(f):
    article_list=[]    
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    list3=[]
    list4=[]
    list5=[]
    list6=[]
    list7=[]
    for i in range(len(articles_ls)):
        for j in range(len(articles_ls[i])-1):
            comment=re.split(r'\W+', f.lower().strip())
            if articles_ls[i][j] in comment:
                if articles_ls[i][j]:

                    if articles_ls[i][3] == 'typea':
                        if articles_ls[i][j] not in list1:
                            list1.append(articles_ls[i][0])

                    if articles_ls[i][3] == 'typeb':
                        if articles_ls[i][j] not in list2:
                            list2.append(articles_ls[i][0])

                    if articles_ls[i][3] == 'typec':
                        if articles_ls[i][j] not in list3:
                            list3.append(articles_ls[i][0])

                    if articles_ls[i][3] == 'typed':
                        if articles_ls[i][j] not in list4:
                            list4.append(articles_ls[i][0])

                    if articles_ls[i][3] == 'typee':
                        if articles_ls[i][j] not in list5:
                            list5.append(articles_ls[i][0])

                    if articles_ls[i][3] == 'typef':
                        if articles_ls[i][j] not in list6:
                            list6.append(articles_ls[i][0])

                    if articles_ls[i][3] == 'typeg':
                        if articles_ls[i][j] not in list7:
                            list7.append(articles_ls[i][0])

    list1 = list(set(list1))
    list2 = list(set(list2))
    list3 = list(set(list3))
    list4 = list(set(list4))
    list5 = list(set(list5))
    list6 = list(set(list6))
    list7 = list(set(list7))

    article_list.append([("ProductA:".split())+list1]+[("ProductB:".split())+list2]+[("ProductC:".split())+list3]+\
                         [("ProductD:".split())+list4]+[("ProductE:".split())+list5]+[("ProductF:".split())+list6]+\
                         [("ProductG:".split())+list7])
    return article_list

lines = sc.textFile("file:///home//XXX//data.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(",")).map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[2].encode("ascii", "ignore")))
articles_all = (lines.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[2],(mapper(x[2].lower())))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found spark to run immensely faster when I loaded my dataset into a Spark DataFrame instead of appending it to a list. Then, I would favour a more functional style over for loops.